# make_shared with template constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, make-shared

I have a class with a template constructor, and want to have a `shared_pointer` to it. Such as:

```
class A;
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr;

class A {
public:
    template <typename T>
    A(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, T data) { ... do something with data ... }

    static A_ptr New(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, T data) {
        return make_shared<A>(arg1,arg2,data);
    }
};
```

I know the line for the `make_shared` isn't right, but don't know the solution. Is it even possible to call `make_shared` with a template constructor? Do I need to make the 'New' function a template one and pass in `A<T>` somehow?...

Comment: Please always add a language tag (if appropriate for the question). The syntax highlighting also checks the tags to find which language the code is in.

Comment: You can have static member function templates. So why don't you try making `New` a function template, like the constructor?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the language tags.

I tried making New a function template and get an error like: 
Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered.
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.

Comment: :( That shouldn't happen. An internal compiler error is always a bug in the compiler. Maybe you can work around the issue, or use a more recent version of gcc. Maybe it's [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56869)?

Comment: I use shared_ptrs and make_shared all over my code, and they're awesome once they work, but they've been giving lots of internal compiler errors every time I get the make_shared parameters wrong. If it's make_shared<A>(arg1, arg2, etc...) even if arg2 doesn't exist it makes a compile error without telling me which file or line. I'm running g++ 4.7.3 so it might just be a bug with make_shared and that version, like you pointed out... Thanks for the link. Maybe I'll just roll back to 4.7.2..

Comment: _"If it's make_shared<A>(arg1, arg2, etc...) even if arg2 doesn't exist it makes a compile error without telling me which file or line."_ ... do you mean an internal compiler error? Because if arg2 doesn't exist of course you'll get an error, and it tells me the file and line

Comment: An internal one, yes, but it doesn't say the line or file for me.

Answer (score 3):

Convert `A::New` into a function template

```
template<typename T>
static A_ptr New(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, T data) {
    return std::make_shared<A>(arg1,arg2,data);
}
```